# JUnit 5 vintage not running tests in nested static classes

Tags: junit, junit5

I have JUnit 4 tests I am trying to run with JUnit 5 Vintage.

I have many tests in nested static classes. Tests in top level classes run fine, but tests in the nested classes don't run.

For example:

```
public class SomeOuterClass {
    @Test
    public void outerTest() {
        // test runs
    }

    public static class SomeInnerTests {
        @Test
        public void someTest() {
            // test doesn't run
        }
    }

    public static class OtherInnerTests {
        @Test
        public void otherTest() {
            // test doesn't run
        }
    }
}
```

I tried setting `junitPlatform.filters.includeClassNamePatterns` to `'^.*Tests?$', '^.*Tests?\$.*$'` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JUnit 5 Vintage added support for running nested static classes in the final release.

By default it only finds classes whose names end in "Test(s)". To include nested static classes that aren't named like that, set the following in your build file.

```
junitPlatform.filters.includeClassNamePatterns '^.*Tests?$', '^.*Tests?\\$.*$'
```

Answer (score -1):

You can execute JUnit 4 with JUnit 5 using [JUnit 5 Vintage](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#dependency-metadata-junit-vintage),

Use it by importing the JUnit Vintage Engine:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    <version>${junit5.vintage.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question at all.